# How do I put specific elements from an array into another array

Tags: java, arrays

How do I put elements from an array into another array in Java?  For example, I have an array {41, -2, 1, 2, -88, 55, -4}  and I want to copy only the negative numbers in a separate array?

I tried this:

```
int[] array = {41, -2, 1, 2, -88, 55, -4};
Arrays.sort(array);

int[] posNum = new int[i];
int[] negNum = new int[i];

for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {

   if (array[i] < 0) {
      array[i] = negNum[i];
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(negNum));
   }

}
```

Comment: Did you tried anything yet?? Please post it.

Comment: Please post the code where you have asked the question not in comment box.

Comment: did you even tried to compile the code which you have posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class arraycheck {





     public static void main(String args[]) {
            int a[] = { 41, -2, 1, 2, -88, 55, -4 };
            int b[] = new int[a.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

                if(a[i] < 0)
                {

                    System.out.println(a[i]);
                    b[i] = a[i];;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, both of you!!! I've just begun to study Java so... forgive me if my questions seem stupid :)

Comment: its ok every1 makes mistake at learning stage

Comment: and if you find any answer useful you should accept by clicking right mark near answer

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    int[] array = {1, 2, -1, 2};
    List<Integer> arlNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (final int number : array) {
        if (number < 0) {
            arlNumber.add(number);
        }
    }

    Integer[] arrayResult = arlNumber.toArray(
            new Integer[arlNumber.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Julien. I'm not that advanced yet, I'm only at the begining.

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can take is to leverage a lambda filter expression if using the Java 8 platform.  This will reduce the amount of boiler plate in your code.  For example:

```
    List<Integer> source = Arrays.asList(41, -2, 1, 2, -88, 55, -4);

    List<Integer> negatives = source.stream().filter(x -> x < 0).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(source);
    System.out.println(negatives);
```

- [41, -2, 1, 2, -88, 55, -4] the source
- [-2, -88, -4] the negatives

Since the source array is a collection (a List), the stream() method provides a sequence of integers in that array.  For each integer from the stream, a filter is applied, and those matching the predicate (x < 0) are provided to the collector, which assembles a list of those matching integers.

This [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html#overview) provides more detail about Java 8 Lambda.